# How to get Mouse Over event to Link Button from Client Side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show some link buttons on a panel in Mouse over event.These buttons visibility will change according to the Logged user type.Please suggest me the way to get this.

I want to call a function from server side.please suggest me the way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance,
Rakesh.

Comment: I got the solution,I have used java script Code for all buttons visible.and i am setting visibility in Load event based on User Type and  changing visibility of buttons again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void onMouseOver(object sender, MouseOverEventargs e) 
{
    LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
    if(loggedinUser == Admin) btn.visibility = visible;        
    else btn.visibility == hidden;
}
```

Or if you want to change all buttons on panel mouse over get all the controls in the panel and do a foreachloop.. if(control is Linkbutton)..

Comment: I didn't find any Mouse over event for Link button .Please tell me how to write this code in server side.?