# Mouse Event for detecting if mouse is hovering over URL

Tags: vb.net, browser, mouseevent

Okay, so I have a basic web browser project (back/forward buttons, stop/refresh, and all the necessary components). I am using the Webbrowser object provided in the toolbox. How can I have it so that when the mouse hovers over a link inside the browser, it displays the link as a string on a label on the form (I.e a status label to tell what URL the mouse is hovering over).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: May this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309049/how-to-get-mouse-over-event-to-link-button-from-client-side) come in handy pal

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        AddHandler WebBrowser1.Document.MouseOver, AddressOf Me.DisplayHyperlinks
    End Sub

Public Sub DisplayHyperlinks(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementEventArgs)
        TextBox4.Text = e.ToElement.GetAttribute("href")
    End Sub
```